# What does char<? mean in scheme?

Tags: scheme, char

what is the difference between:

`char<?` and `char=?` in scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char<?` examines if the numerical value (typically ascii) of the first character is lower than the second.

`char=?` only examines if the characters are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It [compares two characters](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2004/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_6.html#SEC56).